# unlinking comboboxes from each other

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

My project has 3 comboboxes which all are collect similar data (identical options but they will result in different user selections)
I have a datatable which is populated by mysql data - this datatable is linked to each of these comboboxes. Unfortunately when you select one of the listitems on one of these comboboxes it selects that on all 3 of the comboboxes (I dont want it to do this)

items are bound to the comboboxes on load as follows:

```
Private Sub ptnew_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox5.DataSource = insurancecompanies
    ComboBox5.DisplayMember = "IName"
    ComboBox5.ValueMember = "IID"
    ComboBox7.DataSource = insurancecompanies
    ComboBox7.DisplayMember = "IName"
    ComboBox7.ValueMember = "IID"
    ComboBox6.DataSource = insurancecompanies
    ComboBox6.DisplayMember = "IName"
    ComboBox6.ValueMember = "IID"
End Sub
```

How do I prevent this action from happening

Comment: use different datasources; at some level the CBOs represent something different (issuer, underwriter, reinsurer or Life vs Auto vs Home).  Create different DataSources which represent that but just happen to have the same data (or close to it)

Comment: `DataSource` change own `Current` value every time you making changes in the control. Using same DataSource for different controls make selecteditem of the control be the same. Use @Plutonix's advice.

Comment: If you have an answer put it as an answer!!  Sorry - its a pet peeve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone your data sources, so that they are separate entities.

```
Private Sub ptnew_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox5.DataSource = insurancecompanies.Copy
    ComboBox5.DisplayMember = "IName"
    ComboBox5.ValueMember = "IID"
    ComboBox7.DataSource = insurancecompanies.Copy
    ComboBox7.DisplayMember = "IName"
    ComboBox7.ValueMember = "IID"
    ComboBox6.DataSource = insurancecompanies.Copy
    ComboBox6.DisplayMember = "IName"
    ComboBox6.ValueMember = "IID"
End Sub
```

Edit:  Change `Clone` method to `Copy` in order to preserve data